# How To Create an Output?

Tags: c#

How can I display the values `i` and `j` on screen?

```
 internal class Program
 {
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {           
        var i = Calcolatrice.Somma(12, 3);
        var j = Calcolatrice.Sottrazione(45, 34);
    }

    public static class Calcolatrice
    {
        public static int Somma(int x, int y)
        {
            return x + y;
        }

        public static int Sottrazione(int x, int y)
        {
            return x - y;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How did you come to learn C# without learning about `Console.Write()`? Even "Hello World!" can't be done without it. :)

Comment: I hadn't realized that the console.WriteLine () was to be placed in the Main necessarily

Comment: It doesn't really have to be. You can place it in any function and it will work.

Comment: If I try to enter "console.WriteLine (s)" in the "Calcolatrice" does not work for example, and even in the "namespace", I only works if I put it in the "Main"

Comment: As I said, you can write Console.WriteLine() *in any function*, not outside a function. I guess you need some learning before you could really take off. Good luck with that.

Comment: What is the definition of "function"? You mean right class methods?

Comment: You can read the official definition [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173114.aspx). Note that any line of executable code in C# must generally be inside a function body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `Main` method you need to use `Console.WriteLine`. Also you should have `Console.ReadLine` at the end - so that the console window remains on screen - until you hit return - otherwise it will show and quickly disappear. Also, make sure you include the curly braces for your class.

```
internal class Program
{   
   private static void Main(string[] args)
    {   
        var i = Calcolatrice.Somma(12, 3);
        var j = Calcolatrice.Sottrazione(45, 34);
        Console.WriteLine("i = " + i.toString());
        Console.WriteLine("j = " + j.toString());
        Console.ReadLine(); //Press Return to continue    
    }

    public static class Calcolatrice
    {
        public static int Somma(int x, int y)
        {
            return x + y;
        }

        public static int Sottrazione(int x, int y)
        {
            return x - y;
        }
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Program
{   
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var i = Calcolatrice.Somma(12, 3);
        var j = Calcolatrice.Sottrazione(45, 34);
        Console.WriteLine(i);

    }

    public static class Calcolatrice
    {
        public static int Somma(int x, int y)
        {
            return x + y;
        }

        public static int Sottrazione(int x, int y)
        {
            return x - y;
        }
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is a console application:

```
Console.WriteLine("Test");
```

If you mean using the Visual Studio output window:

```
Debug.WriteLine("Test");
```